# What does $0 and $1 mean in Swift Closures?

Tags: arrays, swift, closures

```
let sortedNumbers = numbers.sort { $0 > $1 }
print(sortedNumbers)
```

Can anyone explain what `$0` and `$1` means in Swift?

Another Sample

```
array.forEach {
    actions.append($0)
}
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

`$0` is the first parameter passed into the closure. `$1` is the second parameter, etc. That closure you showed is shorthand for:

```
let sortedNumbers = numbers.sort { (firstObject, secondObject) in 
    return firstObject > secondObject
}
```

Comment: Can i write my own logic in a closure using first parameter and second?

Comment: Yep, that's the entire purpose of the closure.

Comment: thanks mate, your answer helped me understand the better part of closures

Answer (score 89):

**TL;DR**

#### Swift 5.9

`$0`, `$1`, `$2` are [Closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)'s first, second and third **Shorthand Argument Names** or, in other words, implicit parameter names, if you like. The shorthand argument names are automatically provided by Swift. As you know, a closure is a self-contained block of functionality (a function/method without name) that can be passed around and used in your code. Closures have different names in other programming languages – it's ***Lambda*** in Python and Kotlin, or it's ***Block*** in C and Objective-C.

Next, I'll show you how to use Shorthand Argument Names (or SAN for short) in Swift.

#### Higher Order Function + method

Let's assume that we have an array with four elements and we need to sort these elements in reverse alphabetical order. We will create a `viceVersa(..)` method that will pass its content to the higher order function `sorted(..)`.

```
let coffee: [String] = ["Cappuccino", "Espresso", "Latte", "Ristretto"]
```

Regular method used as an argument of a Higher Order Function.

```
func viceVersa(_ n1: String, _ n2: String) -> Bool {
    return n1 > n2
}
var reverseOrder = coffee.sorted(by: viceVersa)

/* RESULT: ["Ristretto", "Latte", "Espresso", "Cappuccino"] */
```

#### Higher Order Function + closure

Nonetheless, the usage of `(String, String) –> Bool` closure instead of the `viceVersa(..)` method in this case is the most practical. Let's see how it works.

**Full closure expression**

```
reverseOrder = coffee.sorted { 
    (n1: String, n2: String) -> Bool in return n1 > n2 
}

/* RESULT: ["Ristretto", "Latte", "Espresso", "Cappuccino"] */
```

**Inferring Type from context in a closure with an implicit return**

It's time to see Swift's vaunted Type Inference in action.

```
reverseOrder = coffee.sorted { n1, n2 in n1 > n2 }

/* RESULT: ["Ristretto", "Latte", "Espresso", "Cappuccino"] */
```

**Shorthand Argument Names in trailing closure**

`$0` and `$1` arguments can make your code more abstract and concise.

```
reverseOrder = coffee.sorted { $0 > $1 }

/* RESULT: ["Ristretto", "Latte", "Espresso", "Cappuccino"] */
```

**Operator method**

And the `operator method` can make the code even shorter.

```
reverseOrder = coffee.sorted(by: >)

/* RESULT: ["Ristretto", "Latte", "Espresso", "Cappuccino"] */
```

#### Map higher order function with a closure

In this example, we'll see how using the `.uppercased()` instance method to replace all lowercase letters in the company name with the uppercase ones.

```
let companies = ["bmw", "kfc", "ibm", "htc"]
```

---

```
let uppercased = companies.map { 
    (item: String) -> String in return item.uppercased() 
}

print(uppercased)

/* RESULT: ["BMW", "KFC", "IBM", "HTC"] */
```

#### $0 in Map's trailing closure

```
let uppercased = companies.map { $0.uppercased() }

print(uppercased)

/* RESULT: ["BMW", "KFC", "IBM", "HTC"] */
```

#### Full closure expression with remainder operator (a.k.a. modulo)

This code shows you how to filter out only even numbers in `[Int]` array using the `%` operator.

```
let numbers: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

```
let filteredNumbers = numbers.filter { 
    (arg: Int) -> Bool in return (arg % 2) == 0 
}

print(filteredNumbers)

/* RESULT: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10] */
```

#### $0 and modulo operator in filter method

```
let filteredNumbers = numbers.filter { ($0 % 2) == 0 }

print(filteredNumbers)

/* RESULT: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10] */
```

#### SAN in variadic functions

Variadic functions are ones that accept any number of parameters. One of the most famous variadic methods is `print(...)`. Shorthand Argument Names are perfect for variadic functions.

```
fileprivate func dessert(_ fruits: String...) -> Bool {

    return fruits.contains { $0 == "Apple" }
}

let contains = dessert("Mango", "Durian", "Papaya")

print(contains)

/* RESULT:  false */
```

#### $0 for existential Sequence type

Here, `allSatisfy()` method indicates whether every element of a sequence satisfies a given predicate or not. The `Any` type represents values of any type. Existential `any` type is used for storing an any kind of value which conforms to a specific protocol. Also, I used here a shorthand syntax for optional binding (shadowing an existing constant).

```
let inputData: [Any]? = [1, 2, 3, "Hello"]

func satisfiesOrNot(_ inputData: any Sequence) -> Bool {
    inputData.allSatisfy { $0 is Int }
}

if let inputData {
    satisfiesOrNot(inputData)
}

/* RESULT:  false */
```

#### Repeating $0

You can multiply $0 multiple times to raise a number to a certain power.

```
let thirdPower = { $0 * $0 * $0 } (25)

print(thirdPower)

/* RESULT:  25^3 = 15625 */
```

#### $0 in closure capturing

Swift method can return a closure, that is capable of capturing some value.

```
func trainer(_ said: String) -> ((String) -> String) {
    return {
        return "¡\(said) \($0)!"
    }
}

let announcement = trainer("Bienvenido a mis cursos")
announcement("RealityKit 2023")

/* RESULT:  "¡Bienvenido a mis cursos RealityKit 2023!"  */
```

#### Shorthand Argument Names $0, $1, $2

```
let math: (Int8, Int8, Int8) -> Int8 = { $0 + $1 - $2 }

func feedClosure() -> (Int8, Int8, Int8) -> Int8 {
    return math
}
feedClosure()(10, 20, 100)

/* RESULT:  (10 + 20 - 100) = -70 */
```

#### $0, $1, $2, $3, $4

In addition to the above, using Shorthand Argument Names you can multiply multiple numbers together.

```
let factorial = { $0 * $1 * $2 * $3 * $4 } (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

print(factorial)

/* RESULT:  5! = 120 */
```

#### Key path expression

Starting from Swift 5.2+ you can access parameters of every instance via key path expression:

```
struct Lighter {
    let manufacturer: String
    let refillable: Bool
}

let zippo = Lighter(manufacturer: "Zippo", refillable: true)
let cricket = Lighter(manufacturer: "Cricket", refillable: false)

let lighters: [Lighter] = [zippo, cricket]

let refillableOnes = lighters.map(\.refillable)

print(refillableOnes)

/* RESULT:  [true, false] */
```

Of course, you can alternatively use a familiar syntax:

**Regular syntax – `$0.property`**:

```
let refillableOnes = lighters.map { $0.refillable }

print(refillableOnes)

/* RESULT:  [true, false] */
```

#### SAN with a subscript

(If you want to know how to implement `negative indexing` in arrays, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489635/swift-negative-indexing-in-arrays/72085448#72085448) please.)

```
let arrays: [[String]] = [["Hello","Hola","你好"], ["world","mundo","世界"]]

let helloWorld = arrays.compactMap { $0[0] }

print(helloWorld)

/* RESULT:  ["Hello", "world"] */
```

One more example with `key` shortcut (Swift 5.6) and a subscript:

```
let dictionaries: [[_ : Any?]] = [[1: "x"], [2: nil], [3: true]]

let values = dictionaries.compactMap { $0[$0.startIndex].value }

print(values) 

/* RESULT:  ["x", true] */
```

Or look at the example of unordered set:

```
let collection: Set<String> = ["One", "", "Three"]

collection.map {
    switch $0.isEmpty {
        case true:
            print("Empty")
        case false:
            print("Element \($0) isn't empty")
    }
}

/*   RESULT:   "Element Three isn't empty"  */
/*             "Empty"                      */
/*             "Element One isn't empty"    */
```

#### SAN in a completion handler

$0 is always convenient in completion handler expressions.

```
let completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)? = {
    if $0 {
        print("It is true, sister...")
    } else {
        print("False")
    }
}
completionHandler?(true)

/* RESULT:  It is true, sister... */
```

Regular syntax, however, is as following:

```
let completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)? = { sayTheTruth in
    if sayTheTruth {
        print("It is true, sister...")
    } else {
        print("False")
    }
}
completionHandler?(false)

/* RESULT:  False */
```

#### SAN in ForEach structure in SwiftUI

```
let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.fixed(70)), count: 5)

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach((1...10), id: \.self) {

                Text("\($0)").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}

/*   RESULT:   1  2  3  4  5   */
/*             6  7  8  9  10  */
```

#### Operator method vs SAN

Operator Method:

```
let records: [Int] = [110, 108, 107, 109, 108]

public func averageSpeed(records: [Int]) throws -> Int {
    let average = records.reduce(0, +) / records.count
    return average
}
try averageSpeed(records: records)

/* RESULT:  108 */
```

Shorthand Argument Names $0 and $1:

```
public func averageSpeed(records: [Int]) throws -> Int {
    let average = records.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 } / records.count
    return average
}
try averageSpeed(records: records)

/* RESULT:  108 */
```

#### $0 as the resulting value

`.onChanged` and `.onEnded` modifiers perform an ***@escaping closure*** when a SwiftUI gesture changed or ended.

```
@State private var rotate: Angle = .zero

var myGesture: some Gesture {
    RotationGesture()
        .onChanged { rotate = $0 }
        .onEnded { angle in rotate = angle }
}

var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .rotationEffect(rotate)
        .gesture(myGesture)
}
```

#### Closure as array's element

```
var closureArray: [() -> Void] = []
var counter: Int = 0

for _ in 1...2 {
    closureArray.append {
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
    }
}

// Identical results:

closureArray.forEach { $0() }
closureArray.forEach { closure in closure() }

/*  RESULT:  */

/*     1     */
/*     2     */
/*     3     */
/*     4     */
```

#### Swift vs Kotlin

Now, let's see how Kotlin's lambda is similar to Swift's closure:

**Swift**

```
let element: [String] = ["Argentum","Aurum","Platinum"]

let characterCount = element.map { $0.count }

print(characterCount)

/* RESULT:  [8, 5, 8] */
```

**Kotlin**

**Kotlin's lambda expression has just one parameter with implicit name: `it`**. In other words, if you have a function literal with exactly one parameter you don’t need to define that parameter explicitly, you can use `it` instead (like `$0` in Swift).

```kotlin
val element = listOf("Argentum","Aurum","Platinum")

val characterCount = element.map { it.length }

println(characterCount)

/* RESULT:  [8, 5, 8] */
```

Comment: Your Python example is needlessly using a lambda. `list(map(len, ....))` would suffice. Personally, unless in a critical performance section, I’d use `[len(v) for v in ...]` because it’s cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Please add swift documentation Link

Comment: @AndyFedoroff Official documentation

Answer (score 33):

It represents shorthanded arguments sent into a closure, this example breaks it down:

**Swift 4:**

```
var add = { (arg1: Int, arg2: Int) -> Int in
    return arg1 + arg2
}
add = { (arg1, arg2) -> Int in
    return arg1 + arg2
}
add = { arg1, arg2 in
    arg1 + arg2
}
add = {
    $0 + $1
}

let result = add(20, 20) // 40
```

Comment: Since the addition operator has the same function signature as that closure, you can break it down even further to just: `add = (+)`

Comment: It should specify the type with `var add:((Int, Int) -> Int) = ...` explicitly for the case 3 and 4, in my swift 5 test.

Answer (score 6):

The refer to the first and second arguments of sort. Here, `sort` compares 2 elements and order them.
You can look up [Swift official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) for more info:

> Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline
>   closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s
>   arguments by the names $0, $1, $2, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

In Addition with @Bobby's Answer I would like to Add an Example

```
var add: (Int,Int,Int)->Int
add = {
//So here the $0 is first argument $1 is second argument $2 is third argument
    return $0 + $1 + $2
//The above statement can also be written as $0 + $1 + $2 i.e is return is optional
}

let result = add(20, 30, 40) 
print(result) // Prints 90
```

Comment: this cannot count as an answer. If you want to add an example, simply edit @bobby's answer

Comment: haha - i actually voted this up, but then, I stopped reading after the first paragraph with the closure definition.  I agree, this isn't an answer, its a transcription of the entire Swift doc on closures.

Answer (score 2):

It is shorthand argument names.

Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s arguments by the names $0, $1, $2, and so on.

If you use these shorthand argument names within your closure expression, you can omit the closure’s argument list from its definition, and the number and type of the shorthand argument names will be inferred from the expected function type. The in keyword can also be omitted, because the closure expression is made up entirely of its body:

```
    reversed = names.sort( { $0 > $1 } )
```

Here, $0 and $1 refer to the closure’s first and second String arguments.