# Delete specific object from LinkingObjects list - Realm Swift

Tags: swift, realm, rlmlinkingobjects

I am currently trying out Realm on a test project and I have been struggling with removing a specific object from a List. [LensDBObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKb6S.jpg) and [ListDBObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7fXi.jpg). LensDBObject contains a list of lenses and ListDBObject are lists of existing lenses. A lens can be in multiple lists and I'd like to remove a specific lens from a specific list but not remove if from the other lists.

Below are my two classes:

```
@objcMembers class LensDBObject: Object {

   dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
   dynamic var manufacturer = ""
   dynamic var series = ""
   dynamic var serial = ""
   dynamic var isSelected = false

   override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
       return "id"
   }

   let objects = LinkingObjects(fromType: ListDBObject.self, property: "lensList")
```

}

```
@objcMembers class ListDBObject: Object {
   dynamic var listName = ""
   let lensList = List<LensDBObject>()
```

}

Below is my code to find a specific lens in the list I want. The values returned are what I expect.

```
let listToSearch = realm.objects(ListDBObject.self).filter("listName == %@", "List 542")
print(listToSearch)
let filteredResults = listToSearch[0].lensList.filter("manufacturer == %@ AND series == %@ AND serial == %@", "Panavision" , "Primo Prime", "407")
print(filteredResults)
```

However, when I try to delete filteredResults, it deletes it from the lensDBOject altogether. I just want to be able to delete this specific lens from this specific list.

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.delete(filteredResults)
}
```

I tried using for loops to get the index of the lens in the list and then delete it directly from that. But it still deletes the lens everywhere.

Am I missing something? Should I be using a one-to-many relationship as opposed to a LinkingObject?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.  You only want to remove the lens from the list, not delete it from the Realm.

```
try! realm.write {
    filteredResults.forEach { lens in
        if let index = listToSearch[0].lensList.index(of: lens) {
            listToSearch[0].lensList.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this will remove from that one specific list all lenses that match your filter.

Edit: Updated to reflect Realm's custom `List` class.

The `if let` is required, because `index(of:)` could potentially return `nil` if the object is not found in the list.  Additionally, we must do it one item at a time rather than getting all the indexes first, since removing an item would cause the index array to be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now I understand why on the RealmBrowser, when I right click on a lens in a list I get the options: Remove object from array or Remove object from array and delete. It needs to be removed, not deleted.
It works :)

Comment: I'm glad that worked, I just typed it in a text editor without testing!

Comment: filteredResults.forEach({ _ in listToSearch[0].lensList.remove(at: 0) })
is the correct code fwiw :)

Comment: No, that's different. `remove(at: 0)` will remove the first element.  `$0` will use the argument passed to `forEach` (the one you have marked as underscore).  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144322/what-does-0-and-1-mean-in-swift-closures

Comment: Sorry for the delay. If I try `filteredResults.forEach{listToSearch[0].lensList.remove(at: $0)}` then $0 refers to a lensDBObject and not and index (Int). I'm deleting from a tableView, so the filteredResult should only return 1 result at a time but I'd be interested do it the right way regardless.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot Realm has its own `List` class that doesn't support removing by object references.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: God this database is an absolute buzzword .... Its mindboggling list.remove(object) isn't a thing that exists in a production quality db in 2019.
Wheee observable shits the bed again...